# Jenkins and Tomcat 7 - Deployed application but context failed to start

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins

When I try to deploy the .war generated by Jenkins manually to Tomcat, it gives me the same thing:

> FAIL - Application at context path /LaudoInfo could not be started

But when I upload the .war generated by InteliJ, it works.

I need to set this auto deploy thing, but I can't understand why my .war from InteliJ works and the one from Jenkins don't.

**Jenkins Log:**

```
Deploying /opt/java/jenkins/workspace/LaudoInfo-Build/target/LaudoInfo.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
Redeploying [/opt/java/jenkins/workspace/LaudoInfo-Build/target/LaudoInfo.war]
Undeploying [/opt/java/jenkins/workspace/LaudoInfo-Build/target/LaudoInfo.war]
Deploying [/opt/java/jenkins/workspace/LaudoInfo-Build/target/LaudoInfo.war]
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/opt/java/jenkins/workspace/LaudoInfo-Build/target/LaudoInfo.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:185)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:909)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:882)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:754)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1007)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:707)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1629)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:506)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /LaudoInfo but context failed to start
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:291)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:102)
    ... 17 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /LaudoInfo but context failed to start
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:611)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:291)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:185)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:909)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:882)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:754)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1007)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:707)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1629)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:506)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**catalina.out file:**

```
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.62.0
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/conf/logging.properties
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xmx2048M
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/endorsed
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/temp
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/VTK5.10.1/build/bin:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 17 more
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 17 more
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8009
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 16 more
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8009
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    ... 16 more
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1948)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5331)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/examples has finished in 55 ms
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/host-manager
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/host-manager has finished in 190 ms
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/manager
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/manager has finished in 240 ms Jun
23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 27885 ms
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 23, 2015 10:44:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: This is a somewhat unhelpful error message, as it's the message Jenkins emits. We need the logs from Tomcat.

Comment: Please consider not putting a log or error message at the top of your post (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: JackWhitelll, already changed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As per catalina.out file:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use :8080
java.net.BindException: Address already in use :8009
```

- Most likely tomcat instance is already running. So perform a clean
  shutdown.
- In other case, port may be in use by other application.

Comment: I'll try to change those and post the results.
Thanks Rajesh.

Comment: Still no changes, context won't start.

Answer (score 1):

You may get this error if you have same @RequestMapping("/somelink") in two different controller classes.